# sql query match results depends on 6 digits

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table contains 6 column and each column have an int value between 1 to 16
there are rows having different combinations

I have an combination 12345?

I want a rows on basis of this sixth number

table

---

```
col1    | col2    | col3 | col4 | col5 | col6 |

1          2         3      4      5      6

1          9         3      4      5      7

1          7         5       2      1     3
```

output :
if sixth number is 6 there is match of 6/6

if number is 7 the match is 5/6

if the number is 3 the match is 2/6
... so on

Comment: Is this MySQL or SQL Server? Also, what is your calculation for the output depending on the sixth number in the row? So sample results.

Comment: This sql server and output should be rows  like sixth Colname 
Selection 6/6 5/6 4/6 3/6 2/6 1/6
Results 
1        0     0    1          1 5     200
2        1      5    200      3       440
.
.
.
.
.
14      10   2     200     40       60

Comment: Any answer   ????